# Conditional Formatting if one of the many parent tag values is selected

Tags: docusignapi

For a DocuSign template I created using a form-fill PDF, I have a group of radio buttons to select an option from a group. There are a couple of text boxes too in the form.

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting such that if one item from the radio button group is selected, then it should display first text box, while if any of the other items in the radio button is selected, then it should display the other text box. Is it possible to do this?

```
For e.g.:

Radio button group => A, B, C , D
Text box => X, Y

Show X if A selected
Show Y if either of B, C, D selected
```

I'm able to implement 'Show X if A selected', but not the conditional option.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've come up with:

```
Make multiple text boxes, one for each radio button in the group:

Radio button group => A, B, C , D
Text box => W, X, Y, Z

Show W if A is selected
Show X if B is selected
Show Y if C is selected
Show Z if D is selected

Where the location of text boxes X, Y, Z are same and hence overlap,
while the position of W is different.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to make conditional text boxes in a DocuSign template is to first create your radio buttons, then create your text boxes and assign them to the condition of the radio buttons.

For example, drag a Radio button onto your document, then click the "gear" icon on the Radio button control. Give it a Group name of "SelectionGroup", and then give it a Value of "GroupA".

Drag a second Radion button onto your document, click the "gear" icon, and give it the Group name "SelectionGroup", but give it a Value of "GroupB".

Now drag a data field onto the document and click the "gear" icon, then select the "Conditional" section of the dialog. Select a Parent Tag of "SelectionGroup" and the Parent Value of "GroupA". Repeat the process for a second data field, only set the Parent Value of this one to "GroupB".

You now have data fields that will only be visible depending upon which radio button condition is active.

Answer (score 0):

Is this related to the DocuSign API or just DocuSign web console (website)?